# Access settings outside of settings app without a root

Tags: settings, file-system

Is there a file hidden somewhere in the internal storage that contains all the system setting preferences? I want to be able to access and modify this file (if it even exists) without rooting my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to modify the Settings' app's files without root access. For the record, if you gain root access in future, then:

#### For Android 4.x-5.x

Look into:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db  # database of Settings Providers/Storage app
/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs                     # some preferences saved by Settings app
```

#### For Android 6.0.x:

Look into:

```
/data/system/users/0/          # look for the files with name beginning with settings_. They serve as the alternative of erstwhile settings.db            
/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs
```

Files under *shared_prefs* and *0* (0 corresponds to User ID 0, the id of primary user)  directories are human readable XML files so you can use a text editor to edit them on the fly. To edit *settings.db*, you can consider an app or processor's architecture (e.g. arm) compatible version of *sqlite3*.

Recommendation: while I've not tried the paid version but only the free version, the app [My Android Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtoolspro) claims to show and allows editing  SharedPreferences as well as the SQLite databases of an app, so for Android 4.x-5.x the said app can be of good use.